# Using PROC GENMOD in SAS how can I create a variable of just the model deviance?

Tags: sas

In R I could just write something like `model$deviance` and `model$df.residual`, but I can't seem to find any way of doing this in SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas R functions produce an object that has sub-objects that you can extract into a variable, SAS procedures create tables. If you see a statistic in some table that you want to use in another part of your program, you can use the Output Delivery System (ODS) to write that table to a data set, as follows:
1) Use the [ODS TRACE ON](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/09/08/ods-table-names.html) statement to discover the name of the table (or look it up in the documentation)
2) Use the ODS OUTPUT statement to write the table to a data set.

For example, if you are interested in the many goodness-of-fit diagnostic statistics (including the statistics for deviance and chi-square residuals), you can discover that the ["Criteria for Assessing Goodness of Fit"](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_genmod_details81.htm) table has the name ModelFit. Therefore, putting
ODS OUTPUT ModelFit=FitStatistics;
inside your PROC GENMOD call will create a data set called "FitStatistics" that contains the statistics you want.